# Image paths are getting converted to data URI instead of URL

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, bundling-and-minification, data-uri

I have a basic React app set up using the Create-React-App tool.

I have an images in my images folder:
/src/img/logo.png

I am including it in one of my component JS files (let's say it's located at /src/Login.js) like this:

```
import logo from "../img/logo.png";
```

I am embedding them into my code like this:

```
<img src={logo} />
```

When I look at the rendered page, I see that the "src" attribute of this image has a data URI. **How can I get the app to generate a URL for this image instead of a data URI?**

Comment: I'm running into this same issue, its frustrating because I am unsure why this is happening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you importing image with import, you can directly use path or take that path in one variable and than pass it to the src like this:

```
 var imgUrl = "../img/logo.png"; 

 <img src={imgUrl} />
```